# Sending Windows Terminal Commands Via Perl

Tags: perl, shell, terminal, command

I am trying to use the [query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186592) terminal server command, but Perl keeps coming back with this error:

```
    'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

If I enter the query command directly into the command prompt I am able to use it, however all of these attempts via Perl result in the above error:

```
    exec("query /help");
    system("query /help");
    `query /help`;
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the way Perl creates a new shell to send commands. Is there a way to have it send directly within the same command shell I am executing the Perl script in?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've just tried it on my system with:

```
print system ( "query /help" );
```

And that works. So my guess might be - `query` isn't in the path when you're using perl.

Failing that though - I'd suggest trying `cmd /c query /help`